# How to prove that a grammar is ambigous/unambigous?

Tags: automation, grammar

If we have the the grammer 
[image: Latex Image]

how to correctly prove that this is unambigious? In my opinion it's hard to describe it so is there a mathematical or logic proof for that?

And then how to proove that L(G) = G? Next thing where it is hard for me to give a logic proof.

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that a grammar is unambiguous by constructing a deterministic parser. You can prove that it is ambiguous by finding a sentence with two different parse trees (or, better said, with two different leftmost or rightmost derivations).

There is no definitive algorithm for producing such proofs, because the ambiguity of a grammar is undecidable.

---

I have no idea what you mean by proving that `L(G) = G`. That's clearly not true, because `L(G)` is a set of strings, while `G` is a grammar. The two objects are from different universes, so they cannot be equal. Perhaps you meant proving that some set of strings `S` is equal to `L(G)`? Again, this problem is, in general, undecidable, but in many useful cases you can construct such a proof. A common strategy is to use induction on the length of the string.